# Scrapy simple LinkExtractor example not working

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get pagination with LinkExtractor to work and have been testing my code on a simple example. I'm trying to scrape all quotes from http://quotes.toscrape.com, but can only return those from the first page.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

```
class LinkExtractorSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "le_spider"

    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/"]

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=(
    '//li[@class="next"]//a/@href')), follow=True, callback="parse")]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield{"Quote": response.xpath('//span[@class="text"]/text()').getall()}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules only work with `CrawlSpider`, so you should subclass your spider from that. Also, `CrawlSpider` uses `parse` internally to extract the links to follow, so you need to change the name of your `parse` method.
Also, the page you specified in `start_urls` will not be going through your callback. For that purpose you can overwrite [`parse_start_url`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url).
Try this and let me know if it worked:

```py
class LinkExtractorSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "le_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/"]
    rules = (Rule(
                LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="next"]/a'), 
                follow=True, 
                callback="parse_page"
            ), )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        for item in self.parse_page(response):
            yield item

    def parse_page(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath('//span[@class="text"]/text()').getall():
            yield {"Quote": quote}
```

Comment: @Omega sorry. Did some research and updated my answer, please check it out.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! It almost works, but it skips results from the first page.

Comment: @Omega That totally makes sense. Would never have thought about that, but yes. I have edited the answer, should now work as expected.

Comment: Glad I could help!